# c++ unit testing with CATCH ambiguous symbol std::size_t

Tags: symbols, ambiguous, catch-unit-test

I have this simple code, and I don't understand why it gives me the red squiggly line under TEST_CASE("") saying it is an AMBIGUOUS SYMBOL std::size_t. It compiles fine but that red line is anoying and I don't understand it.

```
#include <catch.hpp>

namespace Tests
{
   namespace Applications
   {
      TEST_CASE("") <----- AMBIGUOUS SYMBOL std::size_t
      {

      }
   }
}
```

EDIT:
I use Visual Studio as my IDE and it seems to be a problem with VS because I tried it with CLion and no squiggly warnings. I would prefer working with VS so I hope anybody can help me.

Comment: If you give the test case a name and add some code, does it go away? I think this is a false positive from VS intellisense.

Comment: after deleting the .suo file and cleaning the binaries the intellisense errors are gone now. I hope it stays that way :)